# Leaflet WFST - filter layers on the fly

Tags: leaflet, layers, filter, wfs-t

I use [L.WFST](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST#propertyisequalto) plugin to get PostGIS data to my Leaflet app via Geoserver. The dataset is quite large, so I set a BBOX filter on it to show only features within current extent. It works good.
However, I want to update the filter with the new bounds every time the map extent is changed. I try something like that:

```
var layer = new L.WFS({
    url: dataURL,
    typeNS: 'hydro',
    typeName: 'lines',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    geometryField: 'geom',
    showExisting: true, 
    filter: new L.Filter.BBox('geom', map.getBounds(), L.CRS.EPSG4326),
}).addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function () {
    layer.options.filter = new L.Filter.BBox('geom', map.getBounds(), L.CRS.EPSG4326);
    layer.redraw;
});
```

I see that the layer gets a new filter in console, but it hasn't been refreshed. Leaflet seems to assign a filter only once at the first call. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`L.WFS` is extension of Leaflet `L.FeatureGroup` and so has no `.redraw()` method. A look at plugin source revealed `.loadFeatures(filter)` method that seems to work.

And one more thing. Besides `zoomend` event you have to catch also `moveend` event for map panning. And since `moveend` event is fired also at each zoom in/out, there is no need for catching `zoomend` event.

In your case relevant part of the code could looks something like this:

```
map.on('moveend', function () {
  var filter = new L.Filter.BBox('geom', map.getBounds(), L.CRS.EPSG4326);
  layer.loadFeatures(filter);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly!

Comment: Afterthought: since `moveend` event is fired also at each zoom in/out, there is no need for catching `zoomend` event. See modified answer.

Comment: And one more thing. The method above does not take into account that for already visited bounds there is no need to load the layer. That could be avoided using [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) library and it's `turf.union` method to construct visited area polygon/multipolygon and `turf.booleanContains` method to check if map bounds are within already visited area.